# LCD file not create in /dev/fb1

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

I have a IPS 3.5 inch LCD from eleduino, when I mount it on GPIO pins I expect file /dev/fb1 created on customized raspbian in eleduino.com ([this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihulinksxva69nh/RPI_2B_B_B%2B_3.5_320_480_RASPBIAN_201503117.img.zip?dl=0)) to continue in this tutorial :
http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/

what's wrong with this?